# How to bind JS script inside a useEffect with function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a useEffect hook which contains an if-else block and 'B1.X.Change' JS function inside an else.
Now I am unable to bind 'B1.X.Change' to an element 'changeM' inside function component 'func1'. Any help on how this can be achieved is greatly appreciated.

My code looks like below.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (var1 === "") {
    let id = "newvar1";
    if (id === "") {
      if (condition) {
        setP(true);
      } else {
        setP(false);
      }
    } else {
      setvar1(id);
      setP(true);
    }
  } else {
    if (var2 === "xxx" && var3 == null) {
      api
        .getC(var1)
        .then((details) => {
          setvar3(details);
        })
        .catch((reason) => {
          console.log(reason);
        });
    }
    if (condition) {
      //some js script
      B1.X.Change("#changeM", {
        // <do something>
      });
      //some js script
      B1.X.Change("#changeN", {
        // <do something>
      });
      setC(true);
    }
  }
}, [var2, var3]);

function func1() {
  return (
    <Col className="col-4 mt-2 mr-4">
      <Link to="/co" id="changeM">
        {"changeM"}
      </Link>
      <Link to="/co" id="changeN">
        {"changeN"}
      </Link>
    </Col>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean to use the function prototype method [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)?

If so, this is answered here

[How to bind parameters in React hooks' setState() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62035328/how-to-bind-parameters-in-react-hooks-setstate-function)

Side note, It's not clear that `changeM` is an element from your code sample.

Why are you trying to bind `B1.X.Change` to `changeM`?

If you are trying to run some code when you click on changeM and changeN, you use event listeners. In React, you can use the `onClick` property. In the onClick property, you add a function that will be called when the user clicks on that element.

```
function func1() {
  const someFunc = (kind) => {
    // your logic here. The argument allows you to tell if changeM or changeN was clicked.
  }
  return (
    <Col className="col-4 mt-2 mr-4">
      <Link to="/co" id="changeM" onClick={() => someFunc("changeM")}>
        {"changeM"}
      </Link>
      <Link to="/co" id="changeN" onClick={() => someFunc("changeN")}>
        {"changeN"}
      </Link>
    </Col>
   )
}
```

Comment: B1.X.Change contains a JavaScript for a widget which should open upon clicking on changeM and changeN

Comment: I have edited my answer to show how can accomplish what you need to by using React's `onClick` handler, inside of `bind`, which is not possible in React's function components.